# Different links within a div using django

Tags: html, css, django

I have a list item with a mouse over edit button. I want the list item box to redirect to the item url and the edit button to redirect to the edit page.

```
<a class="list-group-item" href = '{{ the_url }}'>
 <div class="list-content" >
  <span class="list-text">{{group_child}}</span>
   <div class="item-actions">
    <span class="btn btn-pure btn-icon" onclick="location.href = '{% url 'mod:editgroup' group_child.id %}'">
     <i class="icon wb-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
   </div>
 </div>
</a>
```

The issue with the above code clicking the edit icon also redirects to list item url. How do I make the edit icon link work

Comment: You have a link inside of a link- that probably isn't going to work. Can you refactor this so that you have two links, with each covering only what you need?

Comment: heres an image of the links https://ibb.co/dAptXA

Comment: I changed it so link is not inside the link and it works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changed the HTML so the DIVs are seperate and it works now.

```
<a class="list-group-item">
  <div class="list-content" onclick="location.href = '{{ the_url }}'">
   <span class="list-text">{{group_child}}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item-actions">
    <span class="btn btn-pure btn-icon" onclick="location.href = '{% url 'mod:editgroup' group_child.id %}'">
     <i class="icon wb-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </span>
  </div>
</a>
```